# Laravel validate array of objects passes but it shouldn't

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation

I'm trying to validate an array of arrays but the validation is passing even if it shouldn't.

Here's my array of arrays :

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'fazfa',
    'link' => NULL,
    'priority' => 'low',
    'comment' => NULL,
    'is_reserved' => false,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => NULL,
    'link' => NULL,
    'priority' => 'low',
    'comment' => NULL,
    'is_reserved' => false,
  ),
)
```

And my validation code :

```
'items.*.comment' => ['nullable', 'string'],
'items.*.link' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1'],
'items.*.name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
'line_color' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
```

This validation fails on **name** but not on `items.*` fields... Do you know why it passes `items.*.link` ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

For testing purpose i have merged items to request and it get excepted result

```
$request->merge(['items'=> [
            [
                'name' => 'fazfa',
                'link' => NULL,
                'priority' => 'low',
                'comment' => NULL,
                'is_reserved' => false,
            ] ,
            [
                'name' => NULL,
                'link' => NULL,
                'priority' => 'low',
                'comment' => NULL,
                'is_reserved' => false,
            ]
         ]]);


            $validator =   Validator::make($request->all(),[
                'items.*.comment' => ['nullable', 'string'],
                'items.*.link' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1'],
                'items.*.name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],

            ]);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($validator->errors());
                exit();
            }
```

and result of that error is

```
Illuminate\Support\MessageBag Object
(
    [messages:protected] => Array
        (
            [items.0.link] => Array
                (
                    [0] => The items.0.link field is required.
                )

            [items.1.link] => Array
                (
                    [0] => The items.1.link field is required.
                )

            [items.1.name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => The items.1.name field is required.
                )

        )

    [format:protected] => :message
)
```

It look like request doesn't have item items key

Comment: Hi, my first code part **Array of arrays** is the result of a ```Log::debug($this->items)``` in the ```prepareForValidation()``` method. So it does have the items in the request. (I'm using laravel request file for validation, not inline validation).

Comment: @Takachi.valdiation works similar even if you use FormRequest.

Comment: Yes but my request contains **items** as I logged it before validation. So even if I merge it, it doesn't work.

Comment: for you merge not required.this i have added for testing in my project. so if your items empty then if you want validation then add 'items'=>'required',

Comment: Already have 
```
'items' => ['required', 'array', 'min:1'],
'items.*.comment' => ['nullable', 'string'],
'items.*.link' => ['required', 'string', 'min:1'],
``` 
But it's still passing the validation. :(

Comment: what you get dd($request->all());

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233047/discussion-between-takachi-and-john-lobo).